# power series expansion for x+1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Write the power series expansion for $x+1$ in summation notation.

Comment: It's already written as a power series.

Comment: how would it be written expanded with the n and stuff

Comment: Think of it as $x+1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k,$ where $a_0=a_1=1$ and $a_k=0$ for $k>1$.

Comment: It is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty x^i - \sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty x^j$ which as geometric series gives $\frac1{1-x} - \frac{x^2}{1-x} =   \frac{1-x^2}{1-x} = 1+x$ as you might hope

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for summation notation; $1 + x$ is already a power series, with every term of order $2$ or higher having the coefficient $0$. You could, if you really wanted to, write it like so
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
where
$$a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } n \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{if } n > 1. \end{cases}$$